# php Error - Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I am following a turtorial on Youtube to set up a basic CMS with php and MySQL.

Now I got a fatal error

> "Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean"

even tho' I have been writing the same as in the turtorial.
The turtorial I am following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ4_eJvnEBc

Here is the code where the fatal error is (list.php):

```
<?php
require '../app/start.php';
$pages = $db->query("
    SELECT id, label, tite, slug
    FROM pages
    ORDER BY created DESC
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($pages);
```

The connection to the database is this code (start.php):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/views');
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/myPHP');
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mycms', 'root', '');
require 'functions.php';
```

Does anyone know what is causing the fatal error?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - might just be a typo for `tite` which should probably be `title`. *who knows*.

Comment: Your query is failing for some reason and returning a BOOLEAN false instead of data. Proper error checking will reveal the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) call returns `false` as it's failed. That's why `fetchAll` can't be executed.

Debug your query! (*I think it's a typo error and `tite` should be `title`*)